# Loki: Known bug in X.Org X Server 1.18.4; how to update?

Tags: release-loki, video-editor

There's a [known bug in X Server 1.18.4](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27222#c24) that is related to SDL-based video playback. It's impacting my ability to use other Ubuntu-packaged video applications such as Flowblade video editor. Flowblade's dev has assisted me isolating the issue via [Black playback screen on Elementary OS 0.4/Loki (Ubuntu 16.04) & MLT 6.0.0.2; works in Shotcut](https://github.com/jliljebl/flowblade/issues/358).

I tried using  “xorg crack pushers” team @ `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` but that almost hosed my install.

How can I update to 1.19?

(EDIT: Cross posted to eOS's [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+question/587929); apologies if this is discourteous.)

Comment: I know this isn't exactly an answer, but this integration is handled upstream here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/xorg-server It looks like they've already updated from 1.17 to 1.18, so I imagine they'll probably ship an update through 1.19.x via a software update in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see 1.19.x was released 2016-11-15. I guess I'm really questioning there's any differences in what eOS is pushing out vs other PPAs. As I mentioned, using “xorg crack pushers” team's PPA for Xenial/16.04 didn't work out too well... good thing ssh was still operating.

Comment: It looks like the Ubuntu X Server PPA includes some distro-specific bugfixes and tweaks. See the answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This upgrade is [handled upstream](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/xorg-server) by the Ubuntu project. [This Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1671799) tracks the integration of xserver 1.19.3 into Ubuntu. There are reports of Ubuntu failing to boot with the new version of X Sever, which would line up with the problems you encountered with the exorg-edgers PPA.

It sounds like this update targets the upcoming Ubuntu 17.04, but I wouldn't be surprised if the update was backported to 16.04 in the future.

You could try installing X Server from the [Canonical X Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/x-staging), which includes the in-progress fixes. Fair warning, though: this package is unfinished and meant for a newer version of Ubuntu. Installing it might hose your installation.

Alternately, you could wait for the upgrade to reach elementary OS, either by a backport to Ubuntu 16.04 or an upgrade to the Ubuntu base in a future version of elementary. If your elementary OS machine is your daily driver, this is probably the safer bet.